# python pandas create new string column cumulatively based on other column condition

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum, accumulate

Suppose I have a dataset (df)

```
Group | Employee_Title | Employee_Name  
A     | Manager        | John     
A     | Analyst        | Adam     
A     | Analyst        | Smith    
B     | Manager        | Bill    
B     | Analyst        | Ed    
B     | Analyst        | Jay
```

I want to create a new column "Group_Manager" so that the new dataset would be:

```
Group | Employee_Title | Employee_Name | Group_Manager 
A     | Manager        | John          | John
A     | Analyst        | Adam          | John           
A     | Analyst        | Smith         | John    
B     | Manager        | Bill          | Bill    
B     | Analyst        | Ed            | Bill       
B     | Analyst        | Jay           | Bill
```

I am looking for python code that can do this in some "cumulative" way, like (not working right now) :

```
df['Group_Manager']=df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda Employee_Title,Employee_Name: Employee_Name if Employee_Title=="Manager" else keep previous Group_Manager)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By retrieving the manager's name for each group and then reindex it according to the main dataframe 'Group' column, you can achieve the results that you desired

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Employee_Title': ['Manager', 'Analyst', 'Analyst', 'Manager', 'Analyst', 'Analyst'],
    'Employee_Name': ['John', 'Adam', 'Smith', 'Bill', 'Ed', 'Jay']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create the Group_Manager column
df['Group_Manager'] = df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda g: g['Employee_Name'][g['Employee_Title'] == 'Manager'].iloc[0]).reindex(df['Group']).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

which results in

```
  Group Employee_Title Employee_Name Group_Manager
0     A        Manager          John          John
1     A        Analyst          Adam          John
2     A        Analyst         Smith          John
3     B        Manager          Bill          Bill
4     B        Analyst            Ed          Bill
5     B        Analyst           Jay          Bill
```

Another approach using `itertools.accumulate`

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

# Sample data
data = {
    'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Employee_Title': ['Manager', 'Analyst', 'Analyst', 'Manager', 'Analyst', 'Analyst'],
    'Employee_Name': ['John', 'Adam', 'Smith', 'Bill', 'Ed', 'Jay']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a series with manager names where title is 'Manager', and NaN elsewhere
managers = df['Employee_Name'].where(df['Employee_Title'] == 'Manager', None)

# Use accumulate to carry forward the manager names
df['Group_Manager'] = list(itertools.accumulate(managers, lambda x, y: x if y is None else y))

print(df)
```

which results in

```
  Group Employee_Title Employee_Name Group_Manager
0     A        Manager          John          John
1     A        Analyst          Adam          John
2     A        Analyst         Smith          John
3     B        Manager          Bill          Bill
4     B        Analyst            Ed          Bill
5     B        Analyst           Jay          Bill
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way we can use itertool.accumulate in this problem?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `itertools.accumulate` as well. You can create `series`with manager names where title is manager else nan and then use `itertools.accumulate `to carry forward the manager names. Do you want that approach as well ?

Comment: Thank you for help me out. Yes, I would like to learn how to use accumulate to solve this problem.

Comment: Answer edited to include `itertools.accumulate`. I hope the edited answer helps you.